# magento how to make a parent menu link which has subcategories not clickable

Tags: magento, menubar

Can someone help me with this please? I'm using Magento CE 1.8.0.0

magento how to make a parent menu link which has subcategories not clickable

I've tried the below codes, they don't work for me either.
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block or Topmenu.php

```
if($category->getLevel()== 2 && $hasActiveChildren) {  
    $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.' onclick="return false;">';
    $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
    $html[] = '</a>';
} else {
    $html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
    $html[] = '<span>' . $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) . '</span>';
    $html[] = '</a>';
} 

if ($category->getID()==[category ID]) {
    $linkClass = 'class="no-click"';
    $html[] = '<a href="javascript:void(0)"'.$linkClass.'>';
}
else{
    $html[] = '<a href="'.$this-&gt;getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>;';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it works on top level only:
app/code/local/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php, line 126 replace this code

```
$html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>'
            . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</span></a>';
```

With :

```
if ($child->hasChildren() && $childLevel == 0 ) {
        $html.= '<a href="#" ' . $outermostClassCode . ' onclick="return false;"><span>'
        . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</span></a>'."\n";
    }
    else {
        $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>'
        . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</span></a>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Titonja has the answer here:

app/code/local/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php

Around line 126. Find this code:

```
$html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>'
            . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</span></a>';
```

Replace with:

```
if ($child->hasChildren()) {
            $html.= '<a href="#" ' . $outermostClassCode . ' onclick="return false;"><span>'
            . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</span></a>'."\n";
        }
        else {
            $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>'
            . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</span></a>';
        }
```

Clear cache. It works for me on Magento 1.8.0.0

Comment: Will these changes be lost when doing an upgrade though?

Answer (score 0):

For people with version 1.6.2, try this:

Look for the file: /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php

Replace line 268:

```
$html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
```

By this conditional:

```
$myParentIds = array(3,6,10);
if (in_array($category->getID(), $myParentIds)){
$linkClass = ' class="no-click"';
$html[] = '<a href="javascript:void(0)"'.$linkClass.'>';
}
else{
$html[] = '<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($category).'"'.$linkClass.'>';
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`app/code/local/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Topmenu.php`

**Around line 126. Find this code:**

```
$html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>'. $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</span></a>';
```

Replace with:

```
if ($child->hasChildren() && $childLevel == 0) {
    $html.= '<a href="javascript::void();" ' . $outermostClassCode . ' onclick="return false;"><span>'. $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</span></a>'."\n";
} else {
    $html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>'. $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</span></a>';
}
```